# Tire and tube keep popping off of the rim

Tags: tire, wheels, rims, tire-pressure

It's the third time now that the tire just pops off my rim, and then the tube blows up as a result. This is all within the span of six months on a brand new bike assembled by a supposedly high-end local bike shop.

Picture:

[image]

- First time I was riding pretty hard downhill (60km/h), fast -- heard a sound as I was slowing down, looked at my tire, it had popped off the rim and the tube was exposed, blew up just a few seconds later...
- Second and third time, I inflated my tire the night before, came in to the basement in the morning, and the tire was seated off the rim. Picture:

[image]

I've gone to the bike shop and they've blamed it on me, on the tire (gave me a new one), on the weather (hard to imagine that the temperature would become hot enough in my basement...)...

Here are the specs.

- Rim: WTB ST i23 (700cc) https://www.wtb.com/products/st?variant=280907388
- Tire: Panaracer T-Serv 700x32 https://www.panaracerusa.com/collections/commuter-city/products/t-serv-protite-folding-urban-commuter-tires?variant=34487835394210

I inflate to the spec using a floor pump, at 95psi.

The problem has only ever happened on the *rear* tire, never on the front (same setup).

What's going on? I have the following theories:

- incompatible combination of rim/tire... it might be that the rim is not rated for such a high pressure and/or the clinch is not deep enough
- defective rim

If anyone has theories and/or an obvious explanation, I would be very grateful. I'm going to my trusted local bike shop tomorrow (not the shop that assembled the bike), since I trust them. But any suggestions on what to look for would be very worthwhile.

Comment: I would suspect that there is something odd about the rim.

Comment: Is your rim hooked?  Or is it tubeless-only ?   Is the other wheel the same kind of rim and tyre?   Mark your rubber and your rim with something indellible to show where it came off, I bet its always the same place/combination.

Comment: The rim is suitably hooked, yes. And is "tubeless ready", not tubeless-only (as far as I know). Other wheel is same rim and tire. I'll take pictures once this happens again (as I'm sure it will) and it'll probably point to the same location on the rim. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: How easy to put the tire one. Does the bead just slide over the rim or does is involve using expletives.... ?

Comment: The usual expletives, gotta use two tire levers to pop it in. Pretty stiff.

Comment: 95psi is VERY high for a 32c tyre.  I suspect Daniel is right and there is something wrong with the rim, but such a high pressure in a large tyre won't be helping

Comment: Assuming that the rim does not have a defect (it may, seeing you have tried different tires and the front wheel/tire combination is not exhibiting the same behavior), one contributing factor may be the width of the rim.  If the rim is narrow and you are trying to put 32's on it, it may be that the tire sidewall on 32's will not mesh as well on a narrow rim and the bead area will be stressed at that sidewall profile, especially at 95 PSI (which is likely more than you need), and if there is a defect/inconsistency in the rim, even more so.

Comment: The rim is rated for 30 to 50 according to the manufacturer. I also worry about a rim defect seeing that the front has not had any comparable problem. I may go back to the shop and ask them to kindly give me a new rim since there's been consistent issues. Even if I had over-inflated by a little bit, the setup shouldn't fail so spectacularly.